# How to subtract 2 hours from user's local time?

Tags: javascript, date

Can anyone give me a simple JavaScript code block that will allow me to display the local time minus 2 hours?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Subtract from another date object

```
var d = new Date();

d.setHours(d.getHours() - 2);
```

- [Complete reference list for Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: I can confirm (via running in Chrome's Javascript console) that it works with a negative value. That is, `d.setHours(d.getHours() - 24)` rewinds d to the same time on the previous day.

Comment: @InzamamMalik yes it's going to change the date. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxgqzP

Comment: it may not work for some particular timezones and timestamps (when the clock was moved forward by 2 or more hours)

Answer (score 45):

According to [Javascript Date Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), you can easily do this way:

```
var twoHoursBefore = new Date();
twoHoursBefore.setHours(twoHoursBefore.getHours() - 2);
```

And don't worry about if hours you set will be out of `0..23` range.
Date() object will update the date accordingly.